# How should I connect to a container using the host rather than the service name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

I'd like to be able to connect to localstack using the host rather than the service name. I have added the `localstack` image to my docker-compose file and set `network_mode: "host"`. I can connect to `http://localhost:8080` from my other containers. But, I can not connect to: `http://localhost:8080` from my host machine. How can I connect to a container using localhost rather than the service name? Not sure if I have misunderstood what `network_mode: "host"` does.

```
version: "3"
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
      - SERVICES=sqs
```

Problem is I'm using CircleCI to run some component tests, but it seems that in CircleCI you can only reference other services on localhost and not via the service name. This means there are some difference between my local environment and test environment configs. I tried running docker-compose in CircleCI but it seems to freak out locally when doing that. So I wanted to see if I can reference localhost between services in docker-compose.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: mac high sierra

Comment: Can you expand on what problem you had with Docker Compose on CircleCI? That works very well in my experience, at least in the Docker executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Docker for Mac runs inside a virtual machine using the xhyve hypervisor not natively on macOS.

When you run the container with `net=host` you are actually using the network of the VM and not the one from your local machine.

This is a known limitation of Docker for mac given the nature of how it works.

The only way to access a container is by using port mapping, so if you remove the `network_mode:"host"` from your docker-compose file it should work as you are already mapping ports.

Comment: But, I can not access other services on localhost but rather by the service name when not using `network_mode:"host"`. Problem is I'm using circle ci to run some component tests, but it seems that in circle ci you can only reference other services on localhost and not via the service name. This means there are some difference between my local environment and test environment configs. I tried running docker-compose in circleci but it seems to freak out locally when doing that. So I wanted to see if I can reference localhost between services in docker-compose.

Comment: Ok. I think I know what you mean. This might be more of an issue on how CircleCI works and how you configured your pipeline there. If you're running localstack with docker-compose and then CircleCI or similar is running a separate service outside your docker-compose service then you won't be able to call by service name as this is only possible for containers running in the same network, so you need to either tell CircleCI to run those components in the same network as your docker-compose services or call it with localhost. I think you need to update your question with this new information.